# what is a reasonable set of values for a core audio AudioStreamBasicDescription for an mp3?

Tags: macos, core-audio, audioqueueservices

I'm try to record some audio to mp3 based on Apple's AudioQueueTool example program; however, when I attempt to create Audio Queue using AudioQueueNewInput I get back the error 1718449215 which according to Apple's documentation means that "The playback data format is unsupported"
My AudioStreamBasicDescription is set like this

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription output_format;
memset(&output_format, 0, sizeof(output_format));
output_format.mSampleRate=44100.0;
output_format.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
output_format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3;
output_format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
output_format.mBytesPerPacket = output_format.mBytesPerFrame =
(output_format.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * output_format.mChannelsPerFrame;
output_format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
output_format.mReserved = 0;
```

I have looked at other simular questions for IOS where the answer was that IOS's version of Core Audio does not support recording mp3's is this the case with the Mac as well?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Core Audio on OS X nor iOS support recording to MP3.